# Reproduce certain rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, rows

I have a table with IDs that represent Individuals (call it id_table) and another table with characteristics an individual can have (call it char_table).

Now I want to add a column to the id_table containing certain values from the char_table. The difficulty, for me, is, that some ID shall get only one characteristic (simple case) and some ID shall get several characteristics. For that reason the rows with these ID that get several characteristics must be reproduced so often until I have matched every characteristic to that ID. 
For Example:
ID '001' shall get the characteristics 'a', 'b', and 'c'. So the row ID='001' must be reproduced 2 times (to get the same row 3 times) and each of these rows shall get one of these 3 characteristics.

I hope I explained intelligible enough.
Anyone an idea how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: If an individual can have multiple characteristics, and a characteristic can be had by multiple individuals, you may need a junction table.

Comment: I first thought of a Join achieving this. But a Join could not reproduce the rows x times, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all cases, you want to do this with an association or junction table.  This table would like like:

```
create table IndividualCharacteristicsr (
    individualId int not null,
    characterId int not null
);
```

(It might also have a unique id itself.)

Each characteristic an individual has would be on a separate row.  So, three characteristics mean three rows.  A typical query using this information would join all three tables:

```
from id_table i left outer join
     IndividualCharacteristicsr ic
     on i.individualId = ic.individualId left outer join
     char_table c
     on c.characteristicId = ic.characteristicId
```

(The `left outer join` includes individuals with no characteristics.)

In Postgres, you could store the characteristics in a string or an array.  Neither is very convenient for joining back to `id_char`.  The better approach is an additional table.

Comment: Thanks for that. Really looks like a suitable solution. One question: What's the meaning of i, c and ic? What's their purpose?

Comment: @hitchcock's_birds . . . Those are table aliases, which are abbreviations for tables.  They make the code more readable and are necessary for self-joins (and in some databases subqueries).